# Expanding a gauge covariant derivative term of a Lagrangian with color and flavor indices

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, differentiation, lie-algebra, yang-mills

I have a Lagrangian which contains the term
$$\operatorname{tr} \left(D_\mu\phi^{\tilde{a}} D^\mu \phi^{\tilde{a}} \right),$$
where $\phi^{\tilde{a}}=\phi^{\tilde{a}a}T^a$ with the indices $a$ and $\tilde{a}$ denoting the gauge and flavor group respectively. Furthermore, $D_\mu$ is the gauge covariant derivative which can be written as
$$
\partial_\mu+ig A_\mu^aT^a
$$
I have a hard time writing the above term explicitly, i.e., I am not sure how to assign color labels (without the tilde) to the fields. Intuitively I expand it as
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\operatorname{Tr}\left( \left[\partial_\mu \phi^{\tilde{a}}+ig A_\mu \phi^{\tilde{a}} \right] \left[ \partial^\mu \phi^{\tilde{a}}+ig A^\mu \phi^{\tilde{a}} \right] \right)\\
&
\operatorname{Tr}\left(\partial_\mu \phi^{\tilde{a}a}\partial^\mu\phi^{\tilde{a}b}T^aT^b+2ig\partial_\mu \phi^{\tilde{a}a}A^{\mu b}\phi^{\tilde{a}c}T^aT^bT^c-g^2A_\mu^{a}\phi^{\tilde{a}b}A^{\mu c}\phi^{\tilde{a}d}T^aT^bT^cT^d\right)\\
&=\partial_\mu \phi^{\tilde{a}a}\partial^\mu\phi^{\tilde{a}a}+2ig\partial_\mu \phi^{\tilde{a}a}A^{\mu b}\phi^{\tilde{a}c}\operatorname{Tr}\left(T^aT^bT^c\right)-g^2A_\mu^{a}\phi^{\tilde{a}b}A^{\mu c}\phi^{\tilde{a}d}\operatorname{Tr}\left(T^aT^bT^cT^d\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to know under which representation your field transforms, the flavor indices play no role here. Assuming $\phi$ is a scalar that transforms in the **adjoint** representation of the color group, sort of implied by the expression the OP writes. First we need to understand how the gauge covariant derivative acts on the field. Recall $T^a$ are infinitesimal generators of the Lie algebra, which means the only product that formally exists between them is the Lie bracket
$$[T^a, T^b] = \sum_c {\rm i} f^{abc}T^c$$
where $f^{abc}$ are the structure constants. Then we have for example for a given flavor $f$, (which does not need to be manipulated)
\begin{align}
D_\mu \phi_f(x) &= \sum_a D_\mu^a \phi_f^a(x) T^a  \\
&= \sum_a \partial_\mu \phi_f^a(x) T^a + \sum_{a,b} {\rm i}\,g\, \phi^a_f(x) A_\mu^b(x) [T^b,T^a]\\
&= \sum_a \partial_\mu \phi_f^a(x) T^a - \sum_{a,b,c}\,g f^{bac}\phi^a_f(x) A_\mu^b(x) T^c
\end{align}

With that you should be able to work out the rest. The issue is, you need to identify the representation of your field. If $\phi$ transformed in the fundamental rep. then it would only have an extra index but no factors of $T^a$.

Comment: Thank you, I should have mentioned that it indeed concerns the adjoint representation. However, if the only product is the lie-bracket, how come that I frequently encounter terms like $Tr(T^aT^bT^c)$? And for example $Tr{T^aT^b}=\delta^{ab}$? Might be a silly question and I have to get a better understanding of Lie-groups.

Comment: Because in physics we are sloppy and those expressions are actually in a representation $tr[\rho(T^a)\rho(T^b)]$ with the representation $\rho$ and then the multiplication of matrices is the usual one, but only after the group element has been represented

Comment: So whenever you write down geometrical and properly defined objects, you only have the bracket. I am afraid within physics, there can be intermediate steps, where it is not obvious that what you have is a bracket, because in practice you use $[A,B]=AB-BA$.

Comment: I get it, thank you very much!

Comment: I am still struggling with a short question. For example the non-abelian field strength contains a term $-i g\left[A_{\mu}, A_{v}\right]$. This would be written as (using the trace of the commutator of the generators) $-ig A^a_\muA^b_\nu Tr([T^a,T^b])=gf^{abc}T^c A^a_\mu A^b_\nu,$ but how is this equal to $g f^{a b c} A_{\mu}^{b} A_{v}^{c}$?

Comment: Generally if you have the trace of a commutator it should give you zero, perhaps you should make a new question with more details :)

Comment: I made a mistake, the trace should not be there! I would say $A^a_\muA^b_\nu[T^a,T^b]=iA^a_\muA^b_\nuf^{abc}T^c$, but this should be equal to $if^{abc}A^b_\muA^c_\nu$. I dont get where $T^c$ goes.